# character rearrange algorithm implementation correctness

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I'm working on the problem below and have posted my code of two different implementation alternatives. My question is, I have two versions of implementation, first version is (1) process most high frequent character until complete, then process another character, (2) 2nd version implementation is, process one character of most high frequent character, reduce its frequency by one, and put it back into heap and get next higher frequency character to process.

I post both version of code below, I have tested and it seems both algorithms are always correct? Are there any issues in either version of code? Thanks.

If both versions are correct, I prefer first version, since it is of better performance dues to not push back into heap (which may cause heap re-arrange internally).

My code is written in Python 2.7.

**Problem:**

Given a string and a positive integer *d*. Some characters may be repeated in the given string. Rearrange characters of the given string such that the same characters become *d* distance away from each other. Note that there can be many possible rearrangements, the output should be one of the possible rearrangements. If no such arrangement is possible, that should also be reported.
Expected time complexity is *O(n)* where *n* is length of input string.

**Examples:**

```
Input:  "abb", d = 2
Output: "bab"

Input:  "aacbbc", d = 3
Output: "abcabc"

Input: "geeksforgeeks", d = 3
Output: egkegkesfesor

Input:  "aaa",  d = 2
Output: Cannot be rearranged
```

**Source code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict
import heapq
def rearrange_v1(source, distance):
    freq_map = defaultdict(int)
    for s in source:
        freq_map[s] += 1
    h=[]
    heapq.heapify(h)
    for c,f in freq_map.items():
        heapq.heappush(h, (-f,c))
    result = [0] * len(source)
    write_index = 0
    while len(h) > 0:
        f,c = heapq.heappop(h)
        f = -f
        while write_index < len(result) and result[write_index] != 0:
            write_index += 1
        if write_index == len(result):
            return None
        i = write_index
        while f > 0 and i < len(source):
            result[i] = c
            i += distance
            f -= 1
        if f > 0:
            return None

    return result

def rearrange_v2(source, distance):
    freq_map = defaultdict(int)
    for s in source:
        freq_map[s] += 1
    h=[]
    heapq.heapify(h)
    for c,f in freq_map.items():
        heapq.heappush(h, (-f,c))
    result = [0] * len(source)
    write_index = 0
    last_pos = defaultdict(int)
    while len(h) > 0:
        f,c = heapq.heappop(h)
        f = -f
        while write_index < len(result) and result[write_index] != 0:
            write_index += 1
        if write_index == len(result):
            return None
        i = write_index
        if c not in last_pos:
            result[i] = c
            last_pos[c]= i
        else:
            i = last_pos[c] + distance
            while i < len(result) and result[i] != 0:
                i += 1
            if i >= len(result):
                return None
            result[i] = c
            last_pos[c] = i
        if f > 1:
            f -= 1
            heapq.heappush(h, (-f,c))

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print rearrange_v1('abb', 2)
    print rearrange_v1('aacbbc', 3)
    print rearrange_v1('geeksforgeeks', 3)
    print rearrange_v1('aaa', 2)
    print '============================'
    print rearrange_v2('abb', 2)
    print rearrange_v2('aacbbc', 3)
    print rearrange_v2('geeksforgeeks', 3)
    print rearrange_v2('aaa', 2)
```

Comment: Wouldn't a question like this, with no actual apparent errors, be more appropriate for the Code Review site?

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I will try later, but most comments from code review are more about code style. I am asking for correctness, so stack overflow might be a better choice. BTW, if you have any advice on my original question, it will be great. :)